# Getting contains function of linked list to work properly in C

Tags: c, debugging, pointers, linked-list, strcmp

I implemented a linked list with a contains function. It uses strcmp like so:

```
    void contains(NODE *head, char data)
{
    NODE *this = head;
    while(this != NULL && strcmp(this->data, data) != 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(this->data, data) == 0){
            printf("Found data %s\n", this->data);
        }
        this = this->next;
    }
}
```

in main I have (I use contains on the last line):

```
NODE *head;
head = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

bool headNode = true;
char userID[1000];
char test[180] = "monkey"; // for testing contains function
while((fgets(userID,1000,stdin) != NULL)){
    if(headNode == true)
    {
        head = insert(NULL, userID);
        headNode = false;
    }
    else
    {
        head = insert(head, userID);
    }
}
contains(head, test);
```

I am still learning C, pointers are still a bit confusing. I have a feeling im making a basic mistake. I want to let the user input some string on their own and check if the list contains that string, but I cant even get contains to work with this test string. I know what I am comparing the test string to is indeed in the list, I have a printList function which I used to verify.

Comment: `strcmp(this->data, data) != 0` and `strcmp(this->data, data) == 0` is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is an pointer to an array which you are passing in function `contains(head, test);`, So formal argument in the caller function should be a pointer as, `contains(NODE *head, char * data) { ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the pointer "test" into function "contains()":

It should be:

```
void contains(NODE *head, char * data)
```